# How to select all structures from a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a json database loaded using pyspark.

I'm trying to access all "x" components of each structures in it.

This is the output of `df.select("level_instance_json.player").printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- player: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 0: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- head_pitch: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- head_roll: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- head_yaw: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- r: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- head_pitch: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- head_roll: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- head_yaw: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- r: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
...
```

I've tried selecting all using the '*' selector but it doesn't work.
`df.select("level_instance_json.player.*.x").show(10)` gives this error:

```
'No such struct field * in 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 101, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 102,...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
list_player_numbers = [el.name for el in df.select("level_instance_json.player").schema['player'].dataType]
list_fields = ['.'.join(['level_instance_json', 'player', player_number, 'x']) for player_number in list_player_numbers]

output = df.select(list_fields)
```

It should work.

Xavier